# UItable view won't scroll first row I want to use like header and I have already section header

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

How can I do to first Row of UITableview to be static (not scrollbale) in iPhone SDK? Like first row will be static.

Now the first row is my header and I want like it need to be static means no scrollable?
I have already section header in that I have number of rows.

Comment: My Idea is you can have a subview inside the table section header so that you can put what ever you want and the rest of the cells will be scrollable..

Comment: I can post a sample code if you need..

Comment: yes, please put it , But my problem is that my first row of the table will be made from UITableview cellfor row at indexpath , now if i put that cell as a subview of my section hederview still it not visible ?
Need help if you have any code please put here Thanks

Comment: Yes I will put a code in a min..

Comment: What i am doing in 
'code'
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 

 NSIndexPath *indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
UITableViewCell *cell=[CaseMasterTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
[sectionInfo.caseheaderView addSubview:cell];
    return sectionInfo.caseheaderView;

Comment: You can add your code by editing your post so that it will be more readable..

Comment: What i am doing in 
`
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 

 NSIndexPath *indexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
UITableViewCell *cell=[CaseMasterTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
[sectionInfo.caseheaderView addSubview:cell];
    return sectionInfo.caseheaderView;
`

Comment: Sorry Newbie to stackoverflow can't edit like redable code :(

Comment: He he.. Its ok.. try both the solutions..  Just upvote if the solutions are helpful and if it solves your problem please mark it correct..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make 2 tableviews - one on top of your view with unscrollable cell, second - under the first one.

Comment: Yep. I suggest to use simple solutions instead of large code hacks :)

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I am creating a view for header section and and adding label and buttons..

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
    if (customView == nil) {
        customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)] ;
        // create the button object
        headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerLabel.opaque = NO;
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

        // If you want to align the header text as centered
        // headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

        headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Child: Name"];

        [customView addSubview:headerLabel];  

        UIButton *aReportButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aReportButton.frame = CGRectMake(270, 3, 38, 38);
        [aReportButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pdf_document.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aReportButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createPDF:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [customView addSubview:aReportButton];
        aVoiceRecordingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aVoiceRecordingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220, 3, 38, 38);
        [aVoiceRecordingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"microphone_document.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aVoiceRecordingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(alertBeforeRecord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [customView addSubview:aVoiceRecordingButton];
    }

    return customView;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44.0;
}
```

In your case you have to increase your table section header height to incldude your section header and the content of your first `UITableViewCell` Content..  Hope this helps..

Comment: I think exactly same if i increase the size of header section it will be work for me inside that i simply addsubview my cell , Thanks let me try it THanks

Comment: @Ravi Did your issue got fixed??

Answer (score 0):

Need to take Custom View for first tableviewCell and add subview in Header sectionView
in

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

set custom view frame just below the header view 
and set cliptobound properly NO for header view.
after that addsubview custom view in header view.

Hopes this Helps.